# Symfony2 ContextErrorException: Warning: filemtime(): stat failed

Tags: php, symfony

When I deploy the application to production server, I got blank page for the production enviroment i.e *app.php*.

However, I tried to figure out the  problem by using my development enviroment "*app_dev.php*", thereby commenting the code restricting me, then I got the following errors:

> ContextErrorException: Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\deploy\Demo\src\SoftMarshal\Bundle\MainBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig
>   in /var/www/web/bilyonedemo/htdocs/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php
>   line 165
>   ContextErrorException: Warning: filemtime(): stat failed for C:\xampp\htdocs\deploy\Demo\src\SoftMarshal\Bundle\MainBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig in /var/www/web/bilyonedemo/htdocs/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php line 165

```
in /var/www/web/bilyonedemo/htdocs/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php line 165
at ErrorHandler->handle('2', 'filemtime(): stat failed for C:\xampp\htdocs\deploy\Demo\src\SoftMarshal\Bundle\MainBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig', '/var/www/web/bilyonedemo/htdocs/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php', '165', array('name' => 'SoftMarshalMainBundle:Default:index.html.twig', 'time' => '1384444091'))
at filemtime('C:\xampp\htdocs\deploy\Demo\src\SoftMarshal\Bundle\MainBundle/Resources/views/Default/index.html.twig') in /var/www/web/bilyonedemo/htdocs/vendor/twig/twig/lib/Twig/Loader/Filesystem.php line 165
at Twig_Loader_Filesystem->isFresh('SoftMarshalMainBundle:Default:index.html.twig', '1384444091') in /var/www/web/bilyonedemo/htdocs/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 4582
at Twig_Environment->isTemplateFresh('SoftMarshalMainBundle:Default:index.html.twig', '1384444091') in /var/www/web/bilyonedemo/htdocs/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 4563
at Twig_Environment->loadTemplate('SoftMarshalMainBundle:Default:index.html.twig') in /var/www/web/bilyonedemo/htdocs/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/TwigEngine.php line 131
at TwigEngine->load('SoftMarshalMainBundle:Default:index.html.twig') in /var/www/web/bilyonedemo/htdocs/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bridge/Twig/TwigEngine.php line 53
at TwigEngine->render('SoftMarshalMainBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array()) in /var/www/web/bilyonedemo/htdocs/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/TwigEngine.php line 79
at TwigEngine->render('SoftMarshalMainBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array()) in /var/www/web/bilyonedemo/htdocs/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Debug/TimedTwigEngine.php line 52
at TimedTwigEngine->render('SoftMarshalMainBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array()) in /var/www/web/bilyonedemo/htdocs/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/TwigEngine.php line 108
at TwigEngine->renderResponse('SoftMarshalMainBundle:Default:index.html.twig', array(), null) in /var/www/web/bilyonedemo/htdocs/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Controller/Controller.php line 106
at Controller->render('SoftMarshalMainBundle:Default:index.html.twig') in /var/www/web/bilyonedemo/htdocs/src/SoftMarshal/Bundle/MainBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php line 11
at DefaultController->indexAction()
at call_user_func_array(array(object(DefaultController), 'indexAction'), array()) in /var/www/web/bilyonedemo/htdocs/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2844
at HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1') in /var/www/web/bilyonedemo/htdocs/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2818
at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in /var/www/web/bilyonedemo/htdocs/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2947
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in /var/www/web/bilyonedemo/htdocs/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2249
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in /var/www/web/bilyonedemo/htdocs/web/app_dev.php line 29
```

Although, it works fine on my local machine.

Comment: Try to clear cache. In given error SYmfony tries to find template at "C:\xampp\htdocs\..." and this is I think your local path, not server's path

Comment: Yes KyleMit, you're right, C:\xampp\htdocs\.. is my local path, but it  clear the cache and even warm up the both the production and the development environment, but yet i got the additional error which i append it on the question due to number of character restriction for comment textarea. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Looks like somewhere in your codebase you'd hardcoded that path. Can you run search for "xampp" string inside project? 'Cause I can't understand why Symfony uses your local path on a server

Answer (score 17):

If it helps, clearing cache, then reinstalling vendors through composer solved my problem:

```
php app/console cache:clear
php composer.phar install
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem caused by error handling parameters set in my xdebug config.  Edited the xdebug config by commenting out the following lines (comment character is the semicolon ";" character.

```
; Error Handling
; xdebug.halt_level = E_WARNING
; xdebug.force_display_errors = 1
; xdebug.scream = 1
```